# Update field without redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a voting system. When a user clicks "Vote" button, the vote value is incremented by one.

But the problem is, this increment action requires redirecting which I do not want to do. 
I'm using will_paginate to paginate my records. 
For e.g., if a user voted for an entity on page 2 of the paginated list, it should stay on page 2. But, currently, it redirects to page 1.

In view I have:

```
<ol>
    <% for number in @numbers%>
    <li>
        <%=number.value%>
        <%=button_to '+1',:action=>:increment,:id=>number.id,:remote=>true%>
        </li>
        <%end%>
        </ol>
        <%=will_paginate @numbers%>
```

In the controller I have:

```
def increment

        number=Digit.find(params[:id])
        number.increment!(:value)

    end
```

But when I don't redirect, I get this error:

```
Missing template digits/increment with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "c:/Sites/tester/app/views"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current solution, rails is looking for a view based on the method controller/method_name .

You need to insert a redirect_to after incrementing the number.

To redirect to the previous page, this is one solution:

```
     redirect_to :back
  rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
     redirect_to root_path
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.That was fantastic!!

Comment: But, it'd be awesome if this update happened like a background task.For e.g, say the vote button is meant for a video thats playing in a popup.It'd be great if vote is incremented, but video continues to play uninterrupted.I thought :remote=>true would do that.Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look up Ajax request with rails. You are right in that you need to do :remote => true in the view, but your controller must be able to handle this request.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to do it with an XHR request.

the controller code would look something like this:

```
def increment
  number=Digit.find(params[:id])
  number.increment!(:value)
  head :ok
end
```

This will return a header as a response with a 200 status, and nothing else. In your javascript code, you just handle the display logic of incrementing the count on the page if the response comes back as 200, and possibly display an error if it doesn't.

Comment: This solution requires some ffort.But I think it is worth a try.

Comment: the head :ok just made my day :-) Cannot be simpler. Thanks @Jason stewart